# Concatenating 2 dataframes vertically with empty row in middle

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a multindex dataframe `df1` as:

```
node    A1      A2
bkt     B1      B2
Month       
1       0.15    -0.83
2       0.06    -0.12


bs.columns
MultiIndex([( 'A1', 'B1'),
            ( 'A2',  'B2')],
       names=[node, 'bkt'])
```

and another similar multiindex dataframe `df2` as:

```
node      A1    A2
bkt       B1    B2
Month       
1      -0.02    -0.15
2          0     0
3      -0.01    -0.01
4      -0.06    -0.11
```

I want to concat them vertically so that resulting dataframe `df3` looks as following:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
```

While concatenating I want to introduce 2 blank row between dataframes `df1` and `df2`. In addition I want to introduce two strings `Basis Mean` and `Basis P25` in `df3` as shown below.

```
print(df3)

Basis Mean      
node    A1      A2
bkt     B1      B2
Month       
1       0.15    -0.83
2       0.06    -0.12

Basis P25       
node      A1    A2
bkt       B1    B2
Month       
1       -0.02   -0.15
2           0    0
3       -0.01   -0.01
4       -0.06   -0.11
```

I don't know whether there is anyway of doing the above.

Comment: it seems you are more looking to a specific way to display your data than really concatenating it?

Comment: can you provide the code to create your df?

Comment: It seems you have misunderstood what a dataframe is. Can you provide more context on why you want to have this as a dataframe?

Comment: I want to make it easy to print to an excel file, this way I don't need to count cells and rows, etc.

Comment: Great. So I understand that the question is rather "How do I print these two dataframes to the same excel sheet?". Is that correct? Please update the question so that it becomes easier to answer it properly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that that is an actual concatenation you are talking about.

The following could already do the trick:

```py
print('Basis Mean')
print(df1.to_string())
print('\n')
print('Basis P25')
print(df2.to_string())
```

Answer (score 1):

Author clarified in the comment that he wants `to make it easy to print to an excel file`. It can be achieved using `pd.ExcelWriter`.

Below is an example of how to do it.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any, Dict, List, Optional

import pandas as pd


@dataclass
class SaveTask:
    df: pd.DataFrame
    header: Optional[str]
    extra_pd_settings: Optional[Dict[str, Any]] = None


def fill_xlsx(
    save_tasks: List[SaveTask],
    writer: pd.ExcelWriter,
    sheet_name: str = "Sheet1",
    n_rows_between_blocks: int = 2,
) -> None:
    current_row = 0
    for save_task in save_tasks:
        extra_pd_settings = save_task.extra_pd_settings or {}
        if "startrow" in extra_pd_settings:
            raise ValueError(
                "You should not use parameter 'startrow' in extra_pd_settings"
            )
        save_task.df.to_excel(
            writer,
            sheet_name=sheet_name,
            startrow=current_row + 1,
            **extra_pd_settings
        )
        worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]
        worksheet.write(current_row, 0, save_task.header)
        has_header = extra_pd_settings.get("header", True)
        current_row += (
            1 + save_task.df.shape[0] + n_rows_between_blocks + int(has_header)
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # INPUTS
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(
        {"hello": [1, 2, 3, 4], "world": [0.55, 1.12313, 23.12, 0.0]}
    )
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(
        {"foo": [3, 4]},
        index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("foo", "bar"), ("baz", "qux")]),
    )

    # Xlsx creation
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
    fill_xlsx(
        [
            SaveTask(
                df1,
                "Hello World Table",
                {"index": False, "float_format": "%.3f"},
            ),
            SaveTask(df2, "Foo Table with MultiIndex"),
        ],
        writer,
    )
    writer.save()
```

As an extra bonus, `pd.ExcelWriter` allows to save data on different sheets in Excel and choose their names right from Python code.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't usually how DataFrames are used, but perhaps you wish to append rows of empty strings in between `df1` and `df2`, along with rows containing your titles?

```py
df1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([["Basis","Mean",""]],columns=df1.columns), df1], axis=0)
df1 = df1.append(pd.Series("", index=df1.columns), ignore_index=True)
df1 = df1.append(pd.Series("", index=df1.columns), ignore_index=True)
df1 = df1.append(pd.Series(["Basis","P25",""], index=df1.columns),ignore_index=True)

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
```